# Hightcharts Display Date month on X-Axis

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I am trying to create a chart that displays data of the last Seven days using Area Chart.

Is there a way to Dynamically make highcharts display last seven days on the x-axis ?

Format: June 2, June 3 etc

[image]

Comment: Why do want highcharts to do the work? Since your data will most likely come from a database, you could enforce your selection more effective there.

Comment: Since the data wont change i think its better i hard code that part of the code into the Javascript itself

Comment: How can dynamic data not change? Wouldn't it be static then?

Comment: i mean.. the date will be from today to last seven days. Using date function we can keep the code static but build dynamic data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not make the xAxis datetime and pass in your daily values then set the xAxis min to 7 days back from your last point?

Here is an example of what to do: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/eLpUd/1/)

Most important link for HighCharts: [Reference](http://www.highcharts.com/ref)

Since we do not know how you are pulling in the data and sending to HighCharts the rest is up to you. The main thing is to read the Reference documentation. HighCharts is crazy powerful and highly customizable. Also, if you have a time-based data set please make sure the data you pass in is in chronological order. While it will not fail to render your jumbled values it will look odd and cause mass hysteria.

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = new Array();

for(i=0;i<30; $i++)
       {
         x[i]="June "+x[i];
       }
```

/* chart object */

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: { },
        .
        .
        xAxis: {
           categories: x
        }
});
```

Before you define x axis array, then to use call highchart chart function.

Comment: i want the date to be dynamic. as in it should take todays date and previous 6days